# C++ interface without inheritance for template functions

Tags: c++, templates, interface, template-specialization

There are two different classes with intersecting set of methods:

```
class A {
public:
    int Value1() { return 100; }
    char Value2() { return "a"; }
    void actionA() { };
}

class B {
public:
    int Value1() { return 200; }
    char Value2() { return "b"; }
    void actionB() { };
}
```

The common part of the classes interface can be described like this:

```
class GenericPart {
public:
  virtual int Value1();
  virtual char Value2();
}
```

Please note that classes `A` and `B` come from some library and therefore cannot be inherited from `GenericPart`.

There is a template function that works with objects implementing methods described in `GenericPart`:

```
template <typename T>
void function(T record) {
    std::cout << record.Value1() << " " << record.Value2() << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to specialize this template function to make it receive only objects that match `GenericPart`?

Comment: When you say *Is it possible to specialize this template function to make it receive only objects that match GenericPart?* Does that mean you don't or do want it to accept `A` and `B` as well?

Comment: Use pointers instead (needed for the polymorphism to work anyway), and create an *overload* that takes a `GenericPart*` argument?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would suggest references to be safer, not having to check for nullptr's.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Seems that exactly this is not possible, since _"classes A and B come from some library and therefore cannot be inherited from GenericPart."_

Comment: What does it mean to **match** `Genericpart`? Are `A` and `B` doing that above?

Comment: @NathanOliver, that means that I want to accept only those objects that have at least `int Value1()` and `char Value2()` methods. Since `A` and `B` have these methods, they can be accepted.

Comment: @Kaz, yes, they do

Answer (score 3):

You could use the C++20 feature: [concepts & constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), but a simpler solution may involve `static_assert`. See the comments in `function` for some explanation

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    int Value1() { return 100; }
    char Value2() { return 'a'; }
    void actionA() { };
};

class B {
public:
    int Value1() { return 200; }
    char Value2() { return 'b'; }
    void actionB() { };
};

class C  { // Has the required functions but with different return types
public:
    double Value1() { return 0.0; }
    double Value2() { return 1.0; }
};

class D  { // Has only one required function
public:
    int Value1() { return 300; }
};


template <typename T>
void function(T record) {
    // Check statically that T contains a `Value1()` that returns an int
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(record.Value1())>, "int Value1() required!");

    // Check statically that T contains a `Value2()` that returns an char
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<char, decltype(record.Value2())>, "char Value2() required!");

    std::cout << record.Value1() << " " << record.Value2() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;

    function(a); // Ok
    function(b); // Ok
    function(c); // causes static_assert to fail
    function(d); // causes static_assert to fail
}
```

Comment: Easy and simple. Using `std::is_same::value` enables this solution back to C++11.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to specialize this template function to make it receive only objects that match GenericPart?

You can't partially specialize a template function.

But you can SFINAE enable/disable different version of it, according to the characteristicsf of `T`.

By example, you can enable `function()` only for `T` supporting `Value1()` and `Value2()` methods as follows

```
template <typename T>
auto function (T record)
   -> decltype( record.Value1(), record.Value2(), void() )
 { std::cout << record.Value1() << " " << record.Value2() << std::endl; }
```

It's more complicated disable a `function()` if doesn't support some methods (but see Timo's answer: given a `has_feature_set` become trivial) so I propose to add an unused parameter of some type (by example, `int`)

```
template <typename T> // VVV  <-- unused argument
auto function (T record, int)
   -> decltype( record.Value1(), record.Value2(), void() )
 { std::cout << record.Value1() << " " << record.Value2() << std::endl; }
```

and develop a generic function that accept an unused type of another (but compatible) type (by example, `long`) and is ever enabled

```
template <typename T> // VVVV  <-- unused argument
void function (T record, long)
 { /* do something with record */ }
```

Now you can write a first level `function()` as follows

```
template <typename T>
void function (T record)
 { function(record, 0); }
```

Observe that you pass `0` (a `int`) to the second level `function()`.

This way is executed the exact match, `function(T, int)`, if available (that is: if `T` support the requested methods). Otherwise execute the generic version, `function(T, long)`, that is ever available.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [max66's approach](https://godbolt.org/z/wZQ_yv) but with return type checking:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    std::false_type has_feature_set_helper(...); // fallback if anything goes wrong in the helper function below

    template <typename T>
    auto has_feature_set_helper(int) -> std::conjunction<
        std::is_invocable_r<int, decltype(&T::Value1), T>, // assert that Value1 is a member function that returns something that is convertible to int
        std::is_invocable_r<char, decltype(&T::Value2), T> // assert that Value2 is a member function that returns something that is convertible to char
    >;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_feature_set = decltype(detail::has_feature_set_helper<T>(0))::value;

template <typename T>
auto function(T record) -> std::enable_if_t<has_feature_set<T>>
{
    std::cout << record.Value1() << " " << record.Value2() << std::endl;
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Dtaorx) is a full example.

Note that the return type checking is not strict, meaning it's checked if the return type is convertible to the type specified in `is_invocable_r_v`.

Comment: Nice. Given that you've developed `has_feature_set`, you could easily add a `function()` version enabled when `has_feature_set<T>` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could design an intermediate template class derived from `GenericPart`. This template you then specialize for A and B.

```cpp
template<class T>
class GenericPartTemplate : public GenericPart
{
public:
  int Value1() override;
  char Value2() override;
}
```

Next it is no longer needed to make your function a template:

```cpp
void function(GenericPart& record) {
    std::cout << record.Value1() << " " << record.Value2() << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to enforce only using A and B you can use [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) to check in compile time GenericPartTemplate is only used with those types.